# local ring of a smooth point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Local ring of a point is a regular local ring iff the point is smooth?

What confuse me is what is the dimension of a local ring at a point x. By definition this ring is just the localization at x with the complement of $m_x$ as multiplicative system. So what is the dimension of this ring? It seems that it equals the maximum of dimension of irreducible component passing through x. Is it right?

Comment: What's your definition of smooth point? Do you assume your ring to be a k-algebra?

Comment: Oh, I define it as a point, s.t. dimension of tangent space at x is equal to the maximal dimension of irreducible component passing through x.

Comment: Regularity is an absolute notion, while smoothness is a relative notion. For example consider the map induced by a finite field extension $k\subset K$. Clearly $\mathrm{Spec} K$ is regular, but it may or may not be smooth over $k$, depending on whether the extension is separable or not.

Comment: Ok, then according to your definition. Regular means $dim_km/m^2=dim A$, so local ring is regular iff 'your definition of smooth point'. However, as Mohan pointed out, the more often seen definition of smoothness is somehow a relative version. With a scheme along we can only talk regularity but not smoothness.